# How to only run WMIC if it has already been installed?

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmi, windows-server-2003, wmic

I am trying to run a batch file that includes some WMIC queries on multiple versions of Windows. Windows 2003 causes the script to hang. It is most likely due to the first time that wmic is being run. The computer will normally output "Please wait while WMIC is being installed.."

Is there anyway to check if wmic is installed and if it is not, do not run it? I do not want to install WMIC on the computers I am running this on if it is not already installed. Should I just skip this query on all Windows 2003?

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm wrong, but I think wmic is present at least from `XP`

This may help

```
@echo off

where /R c:\windows\ wmic.exe >nul 2>nul || (echo/ wmic.exe not found & exit/B)

rem wmic queries here

exit/B
```

Comment: Its present on Windows 2003 systems, but the first time you run it has to be installed. I was going to do:
IF EXIST "C:\Windows\System32\WBEM\wmic.exe" ( do query here) 
 but, like you said it is already present. And I don't want to install it on the systems and it also hangs the script.

Comment: @Gerk check [this](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/rem-enabling-wmi-provider-windows-server-2003)

Comment: Thanks, that is the problem I am facing. I may just skip 2003 for this particular wmic query if I can't figure out a way to check if it installed already.